# URLs omitted by amsrefs

Tags: amsrefs, url

I would like to figure out how to get `amsrefs`/`bibtex` to typeset URLs in bibliography entries.

Here is the system I use for managing my references. I start with a document called `references.ltb`:

```
\begin{bibdiv}
\begin{biblist}

\bib{buskin16}{article}{
    author={Buskin, Nikolay},
    title={Every rational Hodge isometry between two K3 surfaces is
  algebraic},
    date={2016},
    url={arXiv:1510.02852v3 [math.AG]},
}

\end{biblist}
\end{bibdiv}
```

Then this LaTeX file

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsrefs}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}

\cite{buskin16}

\begin{bibdiv}
\begin{biblist}

\bibselect{references}

\end{biblist}
\end{bibdiv}

\end{document}
```

generates this output:

[image]

As you can see, the URL is missing.

Comment: As far as I can see, the `url` field is used only by the `webpage` type.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/428981/arxiv-id-is-displayed-in-bibtex-amsref-but-the-link-does-not-work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `url` field is only available for the `webpage` style. However, it's not difficult to add it to the `article` type.

However, the `eprint` field is already provided. The second example has `eprint` instead of `url` (it doesn't need the redefinition of the `article` type).

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.ltb}
\begin{bibdiv}
\begin{biblist}

\bib{buskin16}{article}{
    author={Buskin, Nikolay},
    title={Every rational Hodge isometry between two K3 surfaces is
  algebraic},
    date={2016},
    url={arXiv:1510.02852v3 [math.AG]},
}

\bib{buskin17}{article}{
    author={Buskin, Nikolay},
    title={Every rational Hodge isometry between two K3 surfaces is
  algebraic},
    date={2016},
    eprint={arXiv:1510.02852v3 [math.AG]},
}

\end{biblist}
\end{bibdiv}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsrefs}
\usepackage{url}

\BibSpec{article}{%
    +{}  {\PrintAuthors}                {author}
    +{,} { \textit}                     {title}
    +{.} { }                            {part}
    +{:} { \textit}                     {subtitle}
    +{,} { \PrintContributions}         {contribution}
    +{.} { \PrintPartials}              {partial}
    +{,} { }                            {journal}
    +{}  { \textbf}                     {volume}
    +{}  { \PrintDatePV}                {date}
    +{,} { \issuetext}                  {number}
    +{,} { \eprintpages}                {pages}
    +{,} { }                            {status}
    +{,} { \url}                        {url}    % <---- ADDED
    +{,} { \PrintDOI}                   {doi}
    +{,} { available at \eprint}        {eprint}
    +{}  { \parenthesize}               {language}
    +{}  { \PrintTranslation}           {translation}
    +{;} { \PrintReprint}               {reprint}
    +{.} { }                            {note}
    +{.} {}                             {transition}
    +{}  {\SentenceSpace \PrintReviews} {review}
}

\begin{document}

\cite{buskin16} \cite{buskin17}

\begin{bibdiv}
\begin{biblist}

\bibselect{\jobname}

\end{biblist}
\end{bibdiv}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect answer, thanks. How do I prevent the space from being removed, between `...852v3` and `[math.AG]`?

Comment: @ZachBlumenstein Load `url` before `amsrefs` with the `obeyspaces` option.