# How to Use BibTeX Citations with the amsrefs Package

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, citing, amsrefs, bibliographystyle

I am using the amsrefs package for my citations, and I am very happy with it. A small problem that I am facing, however, is that arXiv (unlike MathSciNet) does not have an option for downloading references in the amsrefs format; arXiv only allows for downloading references in the BibTeX format. Is there something that I can do to have the arXiv BibTeX citation converted to a amsrefs citation? Please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: Another useful link (and possible duplicate): [Arxiv ID is displayed in BibTeX amsref, but the link does not work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/428981)